# アプリケーション間で構造体を共有する方法について

Tags: go

現在、運用しているサービスにGoで書かれたアプリケーションが二つあります。

この二つのアプリは連携しており、Aのアプリからメッセージを送りBのアプリで受け取るようになっています。
AとBのアプリの間にはキューイングシステム(kafka)を使っています。

AとBでそれぞれ構造体は全く同じなのですが、現在、AとBそれぞれに定義しています。
そのため、構造体に変更があった際はそれぞれのアプリを変更しなければならない状況です。

この構造体を同期したいのですが何かやり方はないでしょうか。
構造体に限らず他にやり方があればそれでも大丈夫です。

Comment: 例えば `import` の仕組みがあるようですが、それを使って C/C++の `include` のようなことは出来ないのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうですね。共通の構造体を定義する別パッケージとして切ってそれをimportする形がありますね。ただそうするとそのパッケージをどこに置くかが悩ましいんですよね。